# What's the Scala for a declaration of "Class<? extends SomeType>"

Tags: scala, parameters, types

I'm obviously missing something about why the following does not compile:

```
trait SomeTrait{
def homepageClass[A <: SomeType]: Class[A]
}

class SomeOtherType extends SomeType

object SomeObject extends SomeTrait{
def homepageClass = classOf[SomeOtherType]
}
```

Answer (score 11):

The problem here is that the following two declarations are different:

```
def homepageClass[A <: SomeType]: Class[A]  // has type parameters
def homepageClass = classOf[SomeOtherType]  // doesn't have type parameters
```

To accomplish what you want you need to declare an abstract type, like this:

```
trait SomeTrait{
  type A <: SomeType
  def homepageClass: Class[A]
}

object SomeObject extends SomeTrait {
  type A = SomeOtherType
  def homepageClass: Class[A] = classOf[SomeOtherType]
}
```

Or

```
trait SomeTrait[A <: SomeType] {
  def homepageClass: Class[A]
}


object SomeObject extends SomeTrait[SomeOtherType] {
  def homepageClass: Class[SomeOtherType] = classOf[SomeOtherType]
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
def homepageClass[A <: SomeType]: Class[A]
```

says "whatever subclass `A` of `SomeType` you give, I can return a `Class[A]`. In particular, it can be called like this:

```
class SomeThirdType extends SomeType

val x: Class[SomeThirdType] = SomeObject.homepageClass[SomeThirdType]
```

A more direct equivalent than Daniel gives is an existential type:

```
trait SomeTrait{
  def homepageClass: Class[A forSome {type A <: SomeType}] 
}
```

or

```
trait SomeTrait{
  def homepageClass: Class[_ <: SomeType] 
}
```

UPDATE: Two differences between solutions I can think about:

1. Existential types produce the same bytecode as Java wildcards (and [their major intended use *is* interoperation with wildcards](http://www.artima.com/scalazine/articles/scalas_type_system.html)).
2. You can write a refinement type for the abstract type member solution:

   ```
    val x: SomeTrait {type A = SomeOtherType} = SomeObject
   ```

   I don't think you can for existential types.

Any others?

Comment: If you now explain the difference between my suggestion and the existential type version, that would be great! :-)